# How set relative-to path logging in thorntail?

Tags: thorntail

I configured logging subsystem in my `thorntail` as below:

```
thorntail:
  logging:
    pattern-formatters:
      LOG_FORMATTER:
        pattern: "%p [%c] %s%e%n"
    periodic-rotating-file-handlers:
      FILE:
        file:
          path: ws.log
          relative-to: /var/log/app/
        suffix: .yyyy-MM-dd
        named-formatter: LOG_FORMATTER
        level: INFO
    handlers:
      - CONSOLE
      - FILE
    root-logger:
      handlers:
        - CONSOLE
        - FILE
    loggers:
        org.jboss.security:
          level: TRACE
        org.jboss.resteasy:
          level: TRACE
```

Now how i can set relative-to property in all setting same `-Djboss.server.log.dir` in wildfly.
Do i should repeat `relative-to` properties in all handlers?

Comment: I think if you remove `relative-to`, it should still default to `jboss.server.log.dir`. Does that not work for you?

Comment: Unfortunately, no